# Django - Getting Current Page

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to add these type of html code to my category pages in django.  So if im on page 4 of mycategory I want to be able to produce this code

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://example.com/mycategory/page/3/" />
<link rel="next" href="http://example.com/mycategory/page/5/" />
```

So I figured I would get the current category url using

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}
```

This helps me get the url

```
/mycategory/?page=2
```

But i'm not sure how to go about getting that last 2 or if im even going about this the right way.

I should also mention if its on page 1, it should only show the next field since there would be no previous.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: http://www.tummy.com/articles/django-pagination/

Also you can watch this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/

Comment: Thank You, I will be checking this out for sure.